# extract specific timestamp period in pcap files

Tags: timestamp, wireshark, editcap

i have one big pcap files and my objective is to extract only certain timestamp period of the traces (for example, the dataset time start from 0 to 200, but i only want between 50 - 100 seconds).

i tried to use editcap tools and use this command

```
 editcap -A "50.000000000" -B "100.000000000"  input_file output_file
```

since my dataset *time* field shows this format.
The problem is, it give error

```
"editcap: "50.000000000" isn't a valid time format"
```

i tried in other way, for example, according to wireshark website, the format should be like this and also end with the same error.

```
The time is given in the following format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
```

Some of the discussed solution in net is to use quote but also give me the error

```
"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"
```

The question is, what is the real format to use the editcap tool to fulfil my objective above.

Answer (score 1):

As the dates of your capture are in UTC time and then may differ from what you see, use the two following commands:

```
>> capinfos -a -e 201609011400.pcap 
File name:           201609011400.pcap
Packet size limit:   inferred: 34 bytes - 96 bytes (range)
Start time:          Thu Sep  1 07:00:00 2016
End time:            Thu Sep  1 07:15:00 2016
>> editcap -A "2016-09-01 07:00:00" -B "2016-09-01 07:05:00" 201609011400.pcap 201609011400_1st_third.pcap
```

Answer (score 0):

```
editcap  -A "2006-12-15 13:17:10" ...
```

worked fine for me (on Windows).

Note: You must use the times as displayed by tshark using the `-tad` option (without the fractional second).

That is: specifying sub-seconds ( `2006-12-15 13:17:10.1234` ) will ignore the sub-seconds part.

Answer (score 0):

You may try tshark this way, instead of using editcap:

```
$ tshark -r input.pcap -R "frame.time_relative >= 50 && frame.time_relative <= 100" -w output.cap
```